# Exit code -1073741510 at bool if statement

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, exit-code

I'm writing a program that prompts a user for a .txt file, then passes the ifstream object and an array of ints to a function - count_letters(ifstream &, int *arrayInts).

The function then reads each character from the ifstream object and stores the frequency of characters from a-z (not case sensitive). Each character is passed to a bool function that checks if it is a non-alphabetical character. For readability I commented off the alphabetVect and checkVect vectors as they are lengthy.

At this point my program quits executing. The for-loop is never executed even when I can see the return is 'true'. The loop before the end of the function printing out the contents of arrayInt is never executed as well.

```
void count_letters(std::ifstream &fileIn, int *arrayInt)
{
    char c;                 // character variable to read from  fileIn
    bool cACReturn;         // charArrayCheck return value
    int aICount = 0;        // count for arrayInt in for loop
    std::vector<char> alphabetVect {// characters 'a' - 'z'};
    while (fileIn.get(ch))
    {
        tempCh = ch;
        cACReturn = charArrayCheck(ch);
        std::cout << "cACReturn = " << cACReturn << std::endl;

        while (1)
        {
            // If ch is an alphabetical character
            if (cACReturn == true)
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < alphabetVect.size(); (i + 2))
                {
                    if (ch == alphabetVect[i] || ch == alphabetVect[i + 1])
                    {
                        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
                        arrayInt[aICount]++;
                    }
                    aICount++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "In count_letter letterArray[" << i << "] = " << arrayInt[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here's the charArrayCheck function:

```
bool charArrayCheck(char charIn)
{
    std::vector<char> checkVect {// non alphabet characters};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < checkVect.size(); i++)
    {

        if (charIn == checkVect[i])
        {
            std::cout << "false in charArrayCheck" << std::endl;

            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            if (i == (checkVect.size() -1))
            {
                return true;
            }

            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Your for loop is not in a function. That should not even compile.

Comment: Check your indexing again.

Comment: `while (1) {...}` You never `break` out of that loop.

Comment: Looks like you lost something when copying the code. `std::vector<char> alphabetVect {// characters 'a' - 'z'};` is not valid.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Also, in the `for`, `(i + 2)` doesn't do anything. Did you want `i += 2`?

Comment: Your title mentions "-1073741510". How do you see this value? (It's probably hexadecimal `0xc000013a` interpreted as a signed integer; that value is mentioned [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308558/how-to-troubleshoot-scheduled-tasks-in-windows-xp-and-in-windows-serve).)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably this line:

```
            for (size_t i = 0; i < alphabetVect.size(); (i + 2))
```

Since it never reassigns `i`, this is an infinite loop. `aICount` keeps incrementing, and eventually `arrayInt[aICount]++` accesses outside the array bounds. This causes undefined behavior, and your program crashes due to all the memory corruption that results.

It should be:

```
            for (size_t i = 0; i < alphabetVect.size(); i += 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm new to programming and I over look simple things like this